# Irreducible representations of a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $A, B$ be finitely generated (noncommutative) algebras over a field $k$ (say, algebraically closed). Can we get all irreducible representations of $A \otimes_k B$ from tensoring representations of $A$ with representations of $B$? I'm especially interested in the case where $A, B$ are the enveloping algebras of finite-dimensional Lie algebras.

Comment: Could this also be tagged tensor-products?

Comment: @Matt: Sure. (and extra characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true for finite-dimensional representations, but false for infinite-dimensional ones.  See pg. 31-32 of [these lecture notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf).

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.